# Doctrine ManyToOne relation: How to save an entity without touching a related entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony 4.4 project using doctrine.
I want to save an entity AEntity , which relates to several other entities.
One of the other entities , BEntity, already exists and cannot be changed by entity AEntity. So AEntity just has to save its relation to BEntity, while BEntity doesn't care about AEntity.

AEntity has a ManyToOne relationship to BEntity. One BEntity can be used by many AEntities.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BEntity", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @SerializerGroups({"view", "collection"})
 */
private ?BEntity $bEntity = null;
```

In BEntity  I have to relationship defined to AEntity.

How can I persist AEntity including saving b_entity_id to the db, without saving BEntity as well?

My problem is, that BEntity has a ManyToOne relationship to CEntity, which causes trouble, when I try to save AEntity. So I would rather not save anything related to BEntity, since it isn't edited anyway.

This is (simplified) how I do it now:

```
$aEntity = new AEntity();
$aEntity->setBEntity($bEntity);

$this->entityManager->persist($aEntity);
$this->entityManager->flush();
$this->entityManager->refresh($aEntity);
```

What do I have to change?

If I remove cascade={"persist"} I get the following error message:

```
Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\AEntity#bEntity' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: BEntity To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).
```

Comment: cascade={"persist"} makes it save BEntity. Try removing it.

Comment: that was how I had it first and then I had that error message: Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\AEntity#bEntity' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: BEntity To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).  I added that to the question

Comment: Is `$bEntity` a "new" entity (as in you created the object recently by doing `new BEntity()`), or an entity you got from the persistence layer? (E.g. `$bEntity = $repository->find($id);`)

Comment: You might try $em->refresh($bEntity) before doing the flush.  This will restore the entity to it's original state so nothing will be written out.  I don't know of any other doctrine specific method of doing this.  I suppose you could have an immutable flag on your bEntity and use it to prevent any changes as well.

Comment: But you probably really want to figure out why the c entity relation is causing problems.  If you are not actually updating any of the b stuff then there should not be any issues.  And if you are updating b then it seems like you would want the changes persisted.

Comment: C entity causes problems, because I haven't got all necessary information for saving it. I didn't care, because I don't have to save it, because there won't be any changes at this point. So that is straightforward. But since nothing should happen with B entity I didn't care getting the missing information. I rather would not save B and C at all.

Comment: I get B entity via find($id), which is executed in a method in a different class and returned to my current class.  it looks like this
$bEntity = $this->bEntityService->getOne($bId);
$this->aEntity->setBEntity($bEntity);

Comment: Is there $this->entityManager->clear(); somewhere in your code? That makes the entitymanager 'forget' all entities and you need to get them again before persisting.

Comment: no clear in sight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

After setting the AEntity values I sent the object into a helper class, where it was changed, especially the connected objects. This led to my problems with BEntity, because now doctrine thought it necessary to save BEntity itself.

By removing any superfluous setting of values in the Helper class finally the saving works as intended.

So if you just want to save the foreign key and not touch the connected entity do as follows:

- Set BEntity in AEntity as a ManyToOne without `, cascade={"persist"}`
- Fetch BEntity by the id from the db.
- Set this result to your AEntity.
- Don't touch it afterwards!
- Save AEntity

Thank you @Vyktoria @yivi @Cerad for your input!